# The file you are trying to open 'file.xls' is in different format than specified by the file extension

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, excel

I am trying to export an excel which contains a string containing html in it. It gives error message :

```
The file you are trying to open 'ExportedHTML.xls' is in different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from trusted source before opening the file .
Do you want to open the file ?
```

On clicking "Yes" on this error message it opened the excel.

I tried to do the follwoing two ways, each gives same error :

```
First :

            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportedHtml.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            this.EnableViewState = false;
            Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            Response.End();
Second:

            excelexport obj = new excelexport();
            obj.downloadFile(htmlContent.ToString(), "File.xls");
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: what is in your string builder??

Comment: sting builder contains html and this html is correct because it renders what i wish to render in excel (when i click on "yes" button of error message)

Answer (score 2):

xls is for excel up to 2007 where it was changed to xlsx (xml based format) or xlsm if it has macros. Find out exactly what type of excel file you are creating and make sure to line up the extension correctly. Also for post 2007 excel files you want content type: 
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

If you can get all three of these things lined up correctly it should make the message go away.

may be of some help
http://www.whatisexcel.net/excel-file-extensions.html

Comment: How to know what typ of excel i am creating using code : "excelexport obj = new excelexport();
            obj.downloadFile(htmlContent.ToString(), "File.xls");" Or by any other way ?

Comment: Actually if the content is html I'm not sure it will ever work without that message. Excel can display tabular data but its not technically a valid format. XLS files are binary and xlsx is xml so it will always complain when its html even if it can render it.